# Make sidebar fill remaining height when already having a sticky header outside the grid containing the sidebar

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-grid, sidebar

I have a sticky top navigation followed by a grid. The grid consists of 2 columns, the left one being a sidebar that shall fill the remaining space no matter how many items it has. If it has more items than can be directly displayed, it shall become scrollable.

How can I do that?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<body class="h-screen">
  <nav class="bg-slate-500 sticky top-0">the navbar</nav>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
    <div class="bg-red-600 min-w-[100px]">left</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-600">main content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a vertical flex layout to the `h-screen` `<body>`:

```html
<body class="h-screen flex flex-col">
```

This then allows the grid to `flex-grow` out to the remaining vertical space if it would otherwise not be tall enough:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1 grow">
```

However, if the sidebar is taller than the remaining space, the whole content becomes scrollable, but you said you only wanted the sidebar to scroll. So to do that, first apply `min-height: 0` to override the implicit `min-height: min-content` applied from being in a vertical flex layout:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1 grow min-h-0">
```

Then, apply `overflow-y: auto` to make the sidebar scrollable (when needed):

```html
<div class="bg-red-600 min-w-[100px] overflow-y-auto">
```

Also a side effect is that the main area also fills the remaining height. To stop this, consider applying `align-self: start`:

```html
<div class="bg-yellow-600 self-start">main content</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<body class="h-screen flex flex-col">
  <nav class="bg-slate-500 sticky top-0">the navbar</nav>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1 grow min-h-0">
    <div class="bg-red-600 min-w-[100px] overflow-y-auto">left</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-600 self-start">main content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<body class="h-screen flex flex-col">
  <nav class="bg-slate-500 sticky top-0">the navbar</nav>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1 grow min-h-0">
    <div class="bg-red-600 min-w-[100px] overflow-y-auto">
      left
      <!-- Element to show scrollability -->
      <div class="h-[200vh] bg-blue-200"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-600 self-start">main content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for that extensive answer! Yet I noted an issue (well didn't specify it): For the 2nd variant, when the main content becomes to tall that it also becomes scrollable, then the whole page including the left part is scrolled. I want to be able to scroll the main part without moving the left part. Can you let me know how that can be done?

Comment: Try applying `overflow-y: auto` to the main content via the `overflow-y-auto` utility class.

Comment: I added that, but it does not fix the issue. Any idea why and how to fix?

Comment: It may be that it's height is not contained. Try applying `max-height: 100%` to the main content via the `max-h-full` utility class.

Comment: that indeed does the job! first of all of course answer accepted as it works all fine. Yet I'd like to understand, what do you mean with "height is [was] not contained"?